# CMake external project BUILD_COMMAND fails

Tags: c++, makefile, build, cmake

I am trying to setup an external cmake project which clones a git repository and builds its contents using **make**.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(rplidar NONE)

include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(RPLidar
    GIT_REPOSITORY      "https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_sdk"
    GIT_TAG             "8291e232af614842447a634b6dbd725b81f24713"
    PREFIX              "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/rplidar"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND   ""
    BUILD_COMMAND       "make -C ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/rplidar/src/RPLidar/sdk"
    INSTALL_COMMAND     ""
)
```

When I try to build it:

```
cmake . -B"build" && cmake --build build
```

I get the following error message:

```
/bin/sh: make -C /path/to/build/rplidar/src/RPLidar/sdk: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/RPLidar.dir/build.make:111: rplidar/src/RPLidar-stamp/RPLidar-build] Error 127
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/RPLidar.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

However if I run **make** manually it works fine

```
make -C /path/to/build/rplidar/src/RPLidar/sdk
```

Why does CMake not register the path and how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't put the quotes.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher wow... that was easy. Thanks!